# Django - Call class as view function

Tags: django

views.py:

```
class ajax_profile():

def __init__(self, request):

    username = request.REQUEST.get('username','')
    email = request.REQUEST.get('email','')
    password = request.REQUEST.get('password','')
    action = request.REQUEST.get('action','')

    options = { 
               'check_username'    : self.check_username(username), 
               'check_email'       : self.check_email(email),
               'forgot_password'   : self.forgot_password(email),
               'login'             : self.login(username, password),
               }
    options[action]

def check_username(self, username):
    return HttpResponse('Test %s' % username)

def check_email(self, email):
    pass

def forgot_password(self, email):
    pass

def login(self, username, password):
    pass
```

urls.py

(r'^ajax_profile/$', 'apps.profiles.views.ajax_profile'),

URL to call

ajax_profile/?action=check_username&username=testtest

ERROR: instance has no attribute 'status_code'

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend doing things this way.  Your views should return HttpResponse objects, while ajax_profile's init method should initialize an instance of ajax_profile.

If you must, you can try having ajax_profile subclass HttpResponse, and use `super` to initialize the HttpResponse at the end of ajax_profile's `__init__`:

```
class ajax_profile(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, request):
        # ...
        response_text = options[action]()
        super(ajax_profile, self).__init__(response_text)
```

Also worth noting, the way `options` is set up, *every method* in the dictionary (`check_username`, `check_email`, etc) will be run every time regardless of the action.  Probably not what you want.

Answer (score -1):

your last line in init() should be `return options[action]`

Comment: When I do so I got this error - 

Exception Value:  __init__() should return None